# Etiquette on deleting answers

Tags: discussion

I just wrote an answer that, on reflection, was misleading/wrong. I know the OP had seen the answer because they commented asking for further details. I then added a comment apologising and explaining that the OP should wait for another user to answer and then deleted my answer.

Will the OP get to see my comment now that I have deleted the answer?

If not, what is the etiquette for retracting answers which you later realise are incorrect?

I feel I should delete the answer as soon as possible, not least to hide my embarrassment, but because I suspect seeing that the question has an answer reduces the probability of someone else reading the question and providing an answer.

Edit: I think I just answered my own question. I should have left the comment on the question rather than the answer.

I'll leave this open in case anyone has other ideas. And I can't bear deleting two posts in one day :(

Answer (score 0):

Nice thoughtful question; as for removing the answer, maybe just follow generally polite behavior in keeping with the Language; perhaps leave a comment to Asker on their question to the effect that the answer was perhaps mistaken: and its possible that there wouldnt Be a different reply anytime soon, or a different reply that would be an improvement

or perhaps could post a reduced version of the answer for which there's more certainty that all of the reduced size answer is correct